# Unity Third Person Starter asset problems with Photon and animations

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, multiplayer, photon

making my multiplayer 3rd person game. However I have problem, that animations don't play on other player's screen, if I walk (object has photon animation view)

I was trying to put
if(_view.isMine) everywhere that my sense thinks it should, but it doesn't work